# Wrapping element inside div

Tags: javascript

Lets assume I have few children `divs` inside some div

[image]

and I want the red one to be wrapped inside new parent `div` but maintain hierarchical order (not appending as a last child, in this case the third child).

[image]

**My approach:**

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');

var parent = red.parentNode;

var new_div = document.createElement('DIV');

parent.appendChild(new_div);

new_div.appendChild(red);
```

1. Find red element
2. Go to parent node of red element
3. Create new element as a child of step 2 but only know that that element will be last one (appendChild method)
4. Append red element in that newly created div

I guess in layman terms, I just want some element to be wrapped and that wrapping to have minimal consequences. Possibly in vanilla Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could use jQuery [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the HTML code for this question? We are not a code writing service. Please post the code you have, the code you are having trouble with and a specific question that we can help with.

Comment: So what did you try? Please look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You need to post code - you're gonna get ripped to shreds otherwise

Comment: create new element. insert new element into desired location. move existing element into new element. $$. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: Also, if you don't want JQuery answers, don't tag your question with JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) a new wrapper element, [insert it before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) the node you want to wrap, and then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the node to the wrapper:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.target');

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');

target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, target);

wrapper.appendChild(target);
```

```css
div div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

.wrapper > .child {
  width: 96px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child target"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```